# "array is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, arrays, photoshop

I'm trying to create a JS script that does the following in Photoshop:

```
var textarray = array("Hello World", "Good morrow", "top of the morning");
```

For each word in the array

1. Open new document
2. Write the word onto a layer
3. Run a photoshop action
4. Save and close

This is my code so far..

```
var textarray = [ "Hello World", "Good morrow", "top of the morning" ];


for (x=0; x < textarray.length(); x++) {


#target photoshop
app.bringToFront();

var strtRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
var strtTypeUnits = app.preferences.typeUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.INCHES;
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.POINTS;

var docRef = app.documents.add(7, 5, 72);

// suppress all dialogs
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;

var textColor = new SolidColor;
textColor.rgb.red = 255;
textColor.rgb.green = 0;
textColor.rgb.blue = 0;

var newTextLayer = docRef.artLayers.add();
newTextLayer.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
newTextLayer.textItem.contents = textarray[x];
newTextLayer.textItem.position = Array(0.75, 0.75);
newTextLayer.textItem.size = 36;
newTextLayer.textItem.color = textColor;

app.preferences.rulerUnits = strtRulerUnits;
app.preferences.typeUnits = strtTypeUnits;
docRef = null;
textColor = null;
newTextLayer = null;

// DO ACTION HERE 
//CLOSE AND SAVE
}
```

It's the array part that isn't working for some reason.. error 24: textarray.length is not a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the original question, `array( ... )` is not how you create an array in JavaScript.

```
var textarray = [ "Hello World", "Good morrow", "top of the morning" ];
```

As for the next problem (which should actually be a separate question), `length` is not a function but a property.

```
for (x=0; x < textarray.length; x++) { 
    ...
```

Comment: Alternatively `var textarray = new Array("Hello World", "Good morrow", "top of the morning");`, which is what it looks like you were trying to do.  Go with Juhana's syntax anyway - it's easier to get right.